# Pullbacks of classifying spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, classifying-spaces

In what follows all the groups will be discrete, not necessarly finite.

Let $f:G\to H$ be a morphism of groups and $H'\to H$ be the inclusion of a subgroup. It seems to me (but correct me if I am wrong) that the pullback $BG\times_{BH}BH'$ is $B(f^{-1}H')$.

If this is true, is there a more general statement that tells you when a commutative square of classifying space is a pullback diagram?

Comment: I guess you are wondering whether the pullback is $(^{−1}')$ (and not $(^{−1})$). The classifying space construction can be viewed as right adjoint (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.04840.pdf), but then it might be necessary to consider the homotopy pullback instead (I'm not sure).

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, I fixed it...thak you for pointing this out and also for the reference, I will take a look at it!

Comment: Relevant question, that you can use the techniques in to answer your question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152493/the-fibre-product-of-two-quotient-stacks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the other hand, if we define $BG$ by the usual simplicial construction, then the functor $B$ does indeed preserve pullbacks.  Indeed, if we start with a pullback square $(G,H,J,K)$ then in the corresponding square of simplicial sets, the square of $n$-simplices is just $(G^n,H^n,J^n,K^n)$, which is again a pullback, so we have a pullback square of simplicial sets.  It is also standard that the geometric realisation functor from simplicial sets to spaces preserves finite limits, so $(BG,BH,BJ,BK)$ is a pullback of spaces.  If the map $H\to K$ is surjective then the map $BH\to BK$ is a fibration and we can conclude that the square $(BG,BH,BJ,BK)$ is also a homotopy pullback.  The same applies if the map $J\to K$ is surjective.  However, as the other answer explains, this story is not homotopy invariant.  It is more usual to consider $BG$ as the name of a homotopy type, and with different models for the relevant homotopy types, the square $(BG,BH,BJ,BK)$ need not be either a pullback or a homotopy pullback.

Comment: Thank you,  I was thinking precisely at the simplicial construction so maybe this answer fits better with my question.

Comment: What was the first hand?

Comment: Was the other answer by R. van Dobben de Bruyn, who answered first.

Answer (score 10):

This is not true. Note that $BG$ is only well-defined up to homotopy equivalence, so the only question that makes sense is when the square
$$\begin{array}{ccc} B\big(G \underset H\times H'\big) & \to & BH' \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ BG & \to & BH \end{array}$$
is a *homotopy* pullback square. For this, you could either work in topological spaces or in Kan complexes (i.e. $\infty$-groupoids). I find it easiest to take the latter point of view, since it is closer to group theory.

The homotopy pullback of a span $X \stackrel p\to Z \stackrel q\leftarrow Y$ can be computed as the space of triples $(x,y,\phi)$ of a point $x \in X$, a point $y \in Y$, and an isomorphism $\phi \colon p(x) \stackrel\sim\to q(y)$ (in the topological setting, you would take $\phi$ to be a path from $p(x)$ to $q(y)$). In the case of groups, there is no choice for the points, so the only choice is $\phi$. The morphisms $(*,*,\phi) \to (*,*,\psi)$ are given by pairs $(g,h') \in G \times H'$ such that $q(h') \circ \phi = \psi \circ p(g)$ (topologically, this would be a homotopy between the paths $p(x) \stackrel\phi\to q(y) \stackrel{q(h')}\to q(y')$ and $p(x) \stackrel{p(g)}\to p(x') \stackrel\psi\to q(y')$). Higher morphisms are determined by their 1-skeleta, so we again get a 1-truncated space, i.e. the nerve of a groupoid.

So what we get in the end is $H/(G \times H')$, where $(g,h') \in G \times H'$ acts by $h \mapsto q(h')gp(g)^{-1}$; the quotient being interpreted in the homotopical sense (as in $BG = */G$). For instance, we see that it is not always connected, so it won't be of the form $BG'$ for any group $G'$. This already happens when $H' = G = 1$ and $H \neq 1$: then the homotopy fibre product is just $H$ viewed as a discrete set.

In general, if $H' = 1$, then the fibre product will be the pullback of the universal cover of $BH$ to $BG$, which is connected if and only if $G \to H$ is surjective. The surjective case is also exactly when the map $N(G) \to N(H)$ (with the groups viewed as one-object categories) is a Kan fibration, so you can indeed compute the homotopy pullback as the ordinary pullback.

Comment: Just one question about the last few lines:  let us agree that BG, BH, BH' are the topological spaces obtained by taking the geometric realization of the nerves N(G), N(H), N(H'). If  $G\to H$ is surjective then the homotopy pullback of the span written on the top of your answer is the same of the ordinary pullback  in the category of topological spaces. Is it right?

Comment: Ah, right, the realisations of the nerves do actually provide somewhat canonical models — e.g. for $\mathbf Z/2$ we get a space *homeomorphic* (rather than homotopy equivalent) to $\mathbf{RP}^\infty$, built from one simplex in each dimension (if I recall correctly). But for $\mathbf Z$, you get something much larger than the circle, so I never really think about this construction. I think your questions have now been addressed by Neil Strickland's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/458324/82179).